# What's the proper way to clean up static python object references in a CPython extension module?

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-extension

The CPython headers define a macro to declare a method that is run to initialize your module on import: `PyMODINIT_FUNC`

My initializer creates references to other python objects, what is the best way to ensure that these objects are properly cleaned up / dereferenced when my module is unloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unload C extension modules at all.  There is just no way to do it, and I know for sure that most of the standard extension modules would leak like crazy if there was.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Digging some more, it looks like the (implemented) PEP 3121 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3121/) explicitly documents this issue, and proposes the `m_clear`, and `m_free` fields in PyModuleDef to remedy it in python 3